# Subset larger Dataframe into smaller ones in R?

Tags: r, select, subset

I have a larger dataframe from which I would like to split up based on 2 columns and a changing 3rd column.

Am on mobile so hard to give a reproducible example so I will try my best to describe.

I have a large Dataframe with 10 columns, the first 2 being ID and Year.

I would like to have smaller ones where the 3rd column will be each of the remaining 8.

So a total of 8 smaller dataframes

I have tried:

newDF1<-select(BIGdf, c("ID", "Year", "3rdVariable"))

newDF2<-select(BIGdf, c("ID", "Year", "4thVariable"))

And achieve the result but is there a way I don't have to write out each individual variable.
Sorry for the poor formatting any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually bad practice to split up data which belongs together.
However, you can automatically create new R objects based on expressions using `assign`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
columns <-
  iris %>%
  colnames() %>%
  setdiff("Species")
columns
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"

columns %>%
  walk(~ {
    data <- iris %>% head(2) %>% select_at(c("Species", .x))
    assign(.x, data, envir = globalenv())
  })

# access created objects
Sepal.Width
#>   Species Sepal.Width
#> 1  setosa         3.5
#> 2  setosa         3.0
Sepal.Length
#>   Species Sepal.Length
#> 1  setosa          5.1
#> 2  setosa          4.9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Worked exactly how I wanted thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to danlooos answer, if you want a Base R solution you could just use a loop:

```
for (col in colnames(iris)[-1:-2]) {
    assign(col, iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", col)], envir = globalenv())
}
```

Or do the same thing and store the resulting data frames in a list, which I personally find somewhat cleaner:

```
new_frames <- list()
for (col in colnames(iris)[-1:-2]) {
    new_frames <- append(new_frames, list(iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", col)]))
}
```

Comment: This does not create new objects using `assign`

Comment: @danlooo Yeah, you're right. I edited the answer to include that.